# How to encrypt a string with AES to a string with only specific characters?

Tags: java, android, cryptography, aes, barcode

I want to use a barcode (code 39) to represent a string, and I want this string to be encrypted using AES.

However, I can only display 43 characters with the [barcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_39). How can I encrypt it so that the result uses only the available set of characters?

Here's what I have so far:

```
public static byte[] encryptAES(String seed, String cleartext)
        throws Exception {
    byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes("ASCII"));
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(rawKey, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NOPADDING");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    return cipher.doFinal(cleartext.getBytes("ASCII"));
}

private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    sr.setSeed(seed);
    kgen.init(BLOCKS, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
    SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
    byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
    return raw;
}

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    String str = "312432432";
    String key = "4AFJ3243J";
    String result = new String(encryptAES(key,str), "ASCII");
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: That "key derivation" method is not a key derivation method. It will produce different results depending on the platform. If I remember correctly, it stopped working as you expect in a recent version of Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is an encoding issue, the problem being you want to convert to a non-standard encoding. What I would do is convert to a base43 encoding. However, you will likely need to implement your own conversion. You should look into how to convert between arbitrary bases, and do the conversion on the byte output of the encryption. Essentially you will take the base10 value of the byte (between 0 and 255 if unsigned), and convert it to two different base43 characters.

A quick Google search for base43 gave me [this](https://code.google.com/p/bitcoin-wallet/source/browse/wallet/src/de/schildbach/wallet/util/Base43.java?name=v3.03). Which I haven't used myself, but looks like it could work.

Comment: As an alternative, Base32 encoding would also fit within the 43 character limit, at the cost of being longer than Base43.  Base32 is more standard, as defined in [RFC 4648](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648)